# Where are my credentials for google-cloud-speech

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I have been using google-cloud speech-to-text using api keys. Now I want to switch to using Google credentials (stored in a JSON file). But I can't figure out how to get those credentials from the google cloud portal. Heck, I can't even figure out where I got the api keys in the first place.

Anybody knows how to get those?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

To get the JSON file you need to have a service account. If you do not have a service account you can follow [Creating a GCP service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating).

Once you have a service account you can generate the JSON file by following [Create service account keys](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys). You can now use this JSON file to authenticate your requests for google-cloud-speech.